# How to store and retrieve data from chrome storage sync

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Hi people I am learning JavaScript and how to make chrome extension with it. Though I can't get my head around storing and retrieving data I am building a project where the user can add certain websites which he wants to block. Now I know such extensions already exists but I am doing so that I can learn JS.

I understand how to use Chrome's storage Api for sync and local and can get the last store value. But I just don't know how to get all the stored values from it. I have read how to retrieve all the keys from the API but then I just don't know how to use to keys to get all the values from those keys.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to Chrome Storage [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage#type-StorageArea),

Pass the key param as null to get all key-values

```js
chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(result) {
 // do with all stored data
});
```

Comment: Yeah I have tried that. But I don't know how to proceed further. I mean I can't wrap my head around getting ahead here.

Comment: Here's a suggestion for you, do ``console.log(result)`` inside the closure, see the type of result you have got, pick the required one. It should be an array of objects.

Comment: Well I had tried doing that as well but nothing shows in my console. I tried leveraging other questions on stackoverflow but could not find the solution. Any help? Here is my code [link](https://imgur.com/a/NJDBkPF)